# Android Studio insert mp3 sound

Tags: android, file, audio, mp3

I tried to add a mp3 song to android, exactly like this explanation, but it's not recognizing my mp3 file as sound, and shows me this error message:

[image]

Comment: Remove spaces from the file name and try again/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the mp3 file in assets folder.

[image: How to create assets folder]

Please clear the empty characters in the filename.